# Give some to get some. Should seeking help be "taxed" with giving some in return (eventually)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers

I am a big supporter of the concept of a self-moderating community. At the same time, I strongly believe everyone in a community should participate in it in a way that creates a net positive effect (or at least - break even). In order for this to work (and work efficiently) the value creation (asking good questions, giving good answers, comments, and positive moderation as a whole) should exceed the value "consumption" (in general - receiving help) or at least equate it. Of course, the full execution of this model is kind of utopic, but the community should strive to reflect it as close as possible.

Okay, enough with the philosophical banter and onto the **clickbait-y** title.

We can generally separate the community members into three general groups:

1. Value Consumers - members who use the platform solely to satisfy their own needs.
2. Members who participate actively by asking good questions and provide value by answering and moderation.
3. Members who use the platform to primarily create value by helping others (once again, by answering and moderation).

Obviously, groups **2** and **3** should be highly valued as indeed they create the net positive effect for the whole community. In short, they're the value creators and we all should be grateful for them.

### So, to the topic itself:

Now, in order to improve further, what can we do to increase the efficiency and move more members from team "consumers" into group 2 or possibly even group 3?

Introduce a mechanism that connects the ability to receive help (by asking questions) to the user's <del>reputation</del> value creation actions. And yes, there is a difference between reputation and value creation. Let's consider a mechanism that uses **tickets** for brevity - **one ticket** = **one question** (the ability to ask one).

A freshly registered user starts with [5-10] tickets. From this point on, tickets are earned by basically being useful to the community:

---

- Asking a good question that nets a positive score (which means that
  either the question is beneficial to someone else or is an overall
  clear, well-structured question).

  For every [3-5] upvotes on your questions (from your own pool of questions, not from a specific one) you're granted a new ticket.

---

- Giving valuable answers to questions (including your own ones).

  For every [2-3] upvotes on answers (once again, from your general pool) you're granted a new ticket. For accepted answers (excluding your own questions) you're granted [1-2] tickets.

---

- For every approved flag you get a ticket.
- For every [2-3] approved suggested edits you get a ticket.

---

The same goes for review queues and higher moderation actions, but members with those privileges should already be more involved in the process.

Now, it is important to note that this mechanism **is not to handicap** new users but to promote collaboration and introduce them to community guidelines and moderation.

So, in short:

### What's the purpose?

Convert more members of the community from pure value consumers to community beneficial value creators.

### Who is affected?

This should affect only users who solely "consume" by asking bad, poorly structured questions in bulk. Seasoned users shouldn't be affected at all by this, as they've basically accrued the tickets naturally (if they need them at all).

### What does the community get from this?

1. Higher overall collaboration between members.
2. New members (and naughty ones) get introduced to the community guidelines sooner.
3. Overall more clear, well structured, and formatted questions.
4. Fewer duplicate questions.
5. Higher moderation participation which leads to a better platform and community in general.
6. Fewer items in review queues.

### Potential risks?

1. People abusing the system by posting bad answers/comments/edits to get around and score some tickets.

**Solution**: The platform already has a mechanism to prevent that so it shouldn't be a problem.

2. Creating new accounts to bypass the restrictions.

**Solution**: **?** Should there be any?

### What are the drawbacks?

I personally don't see any, but this is the topic I am most interested in getting feedback on.

---

The given ticket values and mechanism in general are exemplary. Everything is open for discussion.

Also, this is a general topic that affects all of the Q&A sites in the network (and not only) but I've put it here instead of the **mother META** because, in my opinion, it will mostly benefit the **Stack Overflow** community.

---

### **EDIT**:

First of all, thank you all for the feedback.

I would like to comment on some of the points given.

As a starter, I would like to point out that **reputation** and **contribution** are not the same thing at all and the former doesn't necessarily represent the latter. **Oleg** made a great point about this in the comments below referencing [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite). The reputation system is utterly flawed.

Simple example: A one-sentence question/answer about [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) or how to hide an element in CSS posted in the period 2011-2013 can net you north of **100k** reputation (and will continue to build passively for the foreseeable future). On one hand, yes, your question/answer has helped a lot of people having this exact (no matter how trivial) problem. On the other hand, this will require a total of **3,333** questions/answers each of which being upvoted (without any downvotes) **three** times for someone who is giving assistance at present times to achieve the same reputation gain. I am not complaining about that, I am just pointing out that the system is not objective and doesn't represent actual contributions.

The only way for this to be *somewhat* objective is to compare profiles relative to their registration date, activity time frame, participation in specific tags, and topics, which obviously can't happen.

Furthermore:

1. Edits don't award reputation (after 2k reputation and excluding tag wikis). **[edited for clarity]**
2. Doing reviews don't award reputation.
3. Flagging doesn't award reputation.
4. Giving good answers doesn't necessarily provide adequate reputation.

I strongly believe that privileges shouldn't be based on reputation, but we don't have a better, more accurate system so it is what it is.

---

The next point is that all the feedback was related to the worst-case scenario in which we assume that the malicious user X has exhausted all of his tickets and now has to start producing dummy suggested edits in order for him to continue on his quest to make the life of reviewers (both post and edits) a nightmare. And this is presented as the general case.

10 tickets (questions) is not something you "spend" in a single day. More realistically, it will take you a few months. This is a very important point. It is not like you register and you have to start "earning". You don't have any obligations. You have a question - you just ask. If the question is clear and well structured - you receive help and get upvotes. If not - you don't. You basically have 10 chances to screw up, but I don't think anyone actually aims for this as they just lose their time.

Now, to be honest, I wasn't completely aware of how the current question ban system works because I haven't actually encountered it. Now I see the similarities.

On your journey, it is expected that you're gonna score a few upvotes from your questions. Those upvotes **award** tickets and are actually the main source for askers to accrue them. If you didn't, most probably your questions are bad and should be edited (same solution the question ban counts on). We arrive to the scenario where you're not much of an upstanding member. So you have four solutions:

1. Edit your questions in order to improve them(both to receive help and earn upvotes/tickets).
2. Try to be useful to the community by helping others by answering/commenting. If you do good - you get upvotes and thus tickets. If you don't, you get downvotes and deleted posts which eventually leads to a suspended account.
3. Try to improve other's posts by suggesting edits and flagging bad content. Now, this is a pretty tricky one indeed, I completely agree. If a person can't make his own questions good, how should anybody count on him to edit others' questions? That's a completely valid point. The only thing I would say here is that suggested edits don't award anything. Accepted edits do. Rejected ones lead to privileges suspension and eventual account suspension. In any case, I agree this is not a good idea.
4. Create a new account. No good solution against this no matter what.

Regarding:

> First of all, it allows people to continue asking bad questions as long as they are doing enough community work (suggesting edits). This, IMHO, lowers the question quality instead of raising it.

People will continue asking bad questions until they have an incentive to stop doing so. Like I pointed out in point 3 above, **suggested** edits don't award anything, only accepted ones do. However, like I already mentioned, I wasn't that aware of the question ban mechanism so my suggestion was a solution to prevent such behaviour and now I know such already is in place.

Another good point from Scratte is:

> Apart from edits and answering giving tickets, I think there's another
> slight flaw here. You say that people "get helped" by posting
> Questions. But lots of users post because the Question is missing from
> the repository. They even post their own Answer on it. It's like
> making a word-encyclopedia and then someone saying "Hey, 'dinosaur' is
> missing here. Let me add it". It doesn't matter who puts in the
> description, it was missing all along. Saying Question-askers is
> getting help is focusing on the poster, not the post.

In short: like mentioned, people who post "wiki" type of questions generate tickets from the upvotes to the questions. They're not getting help, they're giving some. That's indeed why I addressed this point preemptively in the original question and those members are actually part of groups 2 and 3.

Lastly, I don't think this should be compared to **pay-to-play**(referencing Oleg's "paywall" association). This should be viewed as a tool for building a stronger community. It can't really be compared to a capital generation scheme model.

To close the topic, I've done some quick "analysis" to see how many users would be affected. Here are some interesting facts, according to [Stack Overflow data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow):

<BlinkingEffect>**Please, ignore the repetition and total inefficiency of my epic queries**</BlinkingEffect>

There are **14,171,069** users [exactly **0** of which have more than **10** questions and **0** answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387315/users-with-more-than-10-questions-and-0-answers). On the other hand [there are **37,319** users with **10+** questions and exactly **1** answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387317/users-with-more-than-10-questions-and-exactly-1-answer). In this setting, [the questions per user are in the range **[11-974]**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387318/users-with-more-than-10-questions-and-exactly-1-answer-ordered-by-question-count) and [the reputation varies between **[1-122,390]**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387321/users-with-more-than-10-questions-and-exactly-1-answer-ordered-by-user-reputation). [The average question score is in the range **[-2.09-144.69]**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387323/users-with-more-than-10-questions-and-exactly-1-answer-ordered-by-question-averag). From those **37,319** users, [**3,351** have **0** or less average question score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387327/users-with-more-than-10-questions-and-exactly-1-answer-with-0-or-less-average-que). From them, [only **1,499** have visited the site the last **6** months](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387329/active-users-with-more-than-10-questions-and-exactly-1-answer-with-0-or-less-aver).

And just for funzies, if we say that a user starts with **10** tickets and each **2** points of question score award a new ticket we get that [**19,534** users have exhausted their tickets](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387341/users-who-have-exhausted-their-tickets), [**11,379** of which are in the range **[-5-0]**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387343/users-who-have-exhausted-their-tickets-by-maximum-of-5) and [**15,615**
in the range **[-10-0]**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387345/users-who-have-exhausted-their-tickets-by-maximum-of-10). [The champion has **974** questions, a reputation of **13,397**, average question score of **0.94** and **-506.22** tickets](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1387351/absolute-question-able-legend)!

It's important to note that we take **only** question upvotes into consideration and ignore everything else.

Once again, thank you all for the feedback provided.

Comment: How many are in group 1 to start the fight?

Comment: Isn't this basically covered with rep rewards already? You get rep from contributions, and even from suggesting edits that get approved, in the beginning. It's also significantly easier to write good answers, than good questions, so the easiest way to get rep is answering...

Comment: For the detailed and constructive post +1 from me. That said, the major drawback of the proposal is that you underestimate the risks. The system for curating answers is *inadequate*. And as with all systems based on *forcing* people to do something instead of *rewarding* them for doing so (which the current system did well until a number of rep earned for question/answer upvotes got "rebalanced"), we *will* see a flux of answers just to get "more tickets" - and we will be the ones dealing with the mess using toothpicks as tooling. Not to mention that the system actually *deters* us from [1/2a]

Comment: [1/2] Since only the ability to ask question (but not to read existing Q&A) is affected, wouldn't this whole proposal only target askers, but not people who drop in to read (consume) from google? So from a pure theoretical point, this is not going to hit the largest consumer group.

Comment: [2/2a] moderating answers by subtracting a rep point for every downvote on an answer. Granted, it matters less the more rep one accumulates, but we cannot deny the psychological effect of being compelled to just skip the curation action.

Comment: [2/2] Quality wise: Wouldn't that allow people to continue asking bad questions as long as they suggest enough edits? In addition: Why would we even want people to suggest more edits? The current main problem is getting the reviews done (review queues are overflowing all of the time). But the group of people your suggestion targets are not qualified to review.

Comment: This looks somewhat like the Question ban, but in reverse (if tickets for edits and Answers are removed from the equation). It'll let users know how many they have left before they even get into the mess. I like the transparency of this proposal.

Comment: To sum up - please no. Penalty-based systems never lead to the proliferation of communities and quality. We reserve hard bans for actually *harmful* contributions (like posting sequences of bad posts), we do not need to prevent good-willing people who mostly on the receiving end of the Q&A model to needlessly suffer.

Comment: @BDL There is quite the difference between asking a question and searching for an answer to one. The latter doesn't consume "resources" in the sense I am talking about and can be beneficial. This proposal is not to target all askers, but only those that ask questions which are beneficial to their specific case only without taking any actions to verify if there isn't an answer already given to another similar question. There are tons of members with 10+ questions(most of which duplicates) without a single answer/comment with a reputation in the range [10-50].

Comment: @OlegValter The thing is, I don't see this approach as a "penalty-based" system. Like I mentioned, people start with a pool of tickets. They can ask questions up to this amount freely, without any obligations. "Requiring" a user to "give something back" in order to continue asking for assistance after the point he has allegedly received help 10 times before that is not a penalty in my perspective. How is this preventing "good-willing" people to suffer?

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't see the link with the proposal. The goal is not to force users to bank reputation in order to [blank] but to involve bigger percentage of the community in mutually-beneficial collaboration. Also, the reputation system doesn't reflect valuable contributions accurately at all.

Comment: Isn't this about incentivizing contributions? The rep system is all about that.

Comment: @zhulien - "tickets" are just a fancy word for a "limit" (just remember "5 charts for free per month"). This is restriction-first and uses the same psychological technique marketing departments employ to hook customers on using services and then presenting them with a paywall. This is not what we would like to be. What's more, limits just incentivize people to look for ways to *circumvent* restrictions rather than contributing on their own accord.

Comment: I would much rather see asking questions being rated by the quality of asking questions – which the q-ban effectively does already. As someone maintaining content, I don't need more people maintaining content, I need less content that needs maintaining.

Comment: Apart from edits and answering giving tickets, I think there's another slight flaw here. You say that people "get helped" by posting Questions. But lots of users post because the Question is missing from the repository. They even post their own Answer on it. It's like making a word-encyclopedia and then someone saying "Hey, 'dinosaur' is missing here. Let me add it". It doesn't matter who puts in the description, it was missing all along. Saying  Question-askers is getting help is focusing on the poster, not the post.

Comment: mutually beneficial collaboration happens when we are gently introducing users to the platform, constantly improve the quality of life of contributors and give curators powerful tools to keep the site clean. If people don't answer enough (and I am one of those who *only* answers, so I know what I am talking about here - you are as well, so I am sure you know that too) it is because the [thoughtful] answerer's life is, frankly, miserable: FGITW problem, outdated answers problem, clueless askers, hordes of help vamps, subpar search, etc. These are the issues we need to push for SE to change.

Comment: @SecurityHound: "Tickets" in the sense that you buy a train ticket... An entry pass, to be expended to write an question...

Comment: *"Asking a good question that nets a positive score (which means that either the question is beneficial to someone else or is an overall clear, well structured question)"* - so when do you sample that? Reputation changes is not something that is time boxed. It might take days, weeks, months for that first upvote or downvote to drop. An edit can change the quality at any time, etc. etc. It is influenced by so many factors, including how active the primary identifying tag is.

Comment: If we could simply get OPs to "pay" for good answers by writing a good question, I'd be happy.

Comment: A TL;DR please.

Comment: @zhulien - well, the main problem I still see with the proposal is that it surely encourages answers by *prohibiting* users from asking, but it does not encourage *good* answers. There is also so many things that could (and will) go wrong: placeholder answers, accept/upvote whoring if only upvoted answers count, answering mega dupes instead of closing questions (which already happens a lot), influx of answerers in general (who are not necessarily capable of being good answerers - just as not everyone are capable of being good askers).

Comment: @OlegValter Now this is a reasonable, good critique. I completely agree with you. The thing is ALL of those problems are already an ongoing fact. They're not something that will come if such a system gets implemented. And the current "reward" reputation system encourages this. I am not proposing a solution to rule them all and abolish all human problems. Solutions should build on one another. I just proposed a mechanism to award the privilege to ask questions to people who aren't actually a burden. Everything else (like what gets counted towards the ticket score) is entirely up for discussion.

Comment: @OlegValter If you look at the situation from above, this community basically represents the human population as a whole. If you want a healthy community everyone should participate in some beneficial (to the whole) way. If you just leech from the limited resources, you're basically just doing harm. And not trying to integrate and incentivize people to participate actively will just lead to more people being leeches. It's just how the world works. Political, economic and community-driven systems have much in common and you can take a solution from one to solve a problem in another.

Comment: That's exactly the biggest issue I see in the proposal - considering people on the receiving end as "leeches" of the community. They are not - they are just as much a part of the ecosystem as answerers. Both are limited resources that should be cultivated and cherished - not by imposing artificial limits, but by making the lives of both parties easier and more joyful (adequate tooling is a crucial part of that) or at least less miserable.

Comment: @OlegValter Please, don't take my words out of context. I haven't said people on the receiving end are "leeches". I said a chunk of them(the ones who entirely consume for their own good disregarding anyone else, not providing any feedback to the helpers and who are members of the cult "clean after me") are behaving like ones. There's a humongous difference! And I stated this already a couple of times both in the question and in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I probably shouldn't have referenced the leech part - the idea was to say that the proposal treats askers as inferior to answerers making them second-class citizens by default making them "earn" their *right* to ask. This is what bothers me with the proposal. i already mentioned that help vamps are unlikely to fall in line with or without quotas, so the real victims will be exactly well-meaning users. We should strive to educate and onboard them, add more quality checks, help curators do their job in cleanup so as good answerers can connect to good askers instead.

Comment: @OlegValter Yes, that's a point that I can stay behind. My suggestion was just that - a suggestion, a quite unpolished one. Thanks to the feedback I got I noticed some of the flaws that I didn't consider before that. Thank you for the time you took to be a part of the discussion and present some of those flaws and also for your attitude towards it.

Comment: @charlietfl Already working on v2, including introduction of options, futures and other currency pairs based on it. It will be the new safe haven. Pushing it as the modern version of the gold standard.

Comment: @zhulien - FYI: You don’t have to notate edits within your question.  Everyone can see you edited your question.

Comment: @zhulien - nah, it's a relic of the good old "EDIT:" vs edit history debate (I am a proponent of the latter as well). Given that your proposal is well written but is highly unlikely to be accepted, we can at least smooth the reading experience for future readers (if anything, the proposal is a good anchor point for future ones retreading the same ground) as there is a lot to read through. So I don't think Security Hound is mocking you in any way.

Comment: @OlegValter Like I mentioned, this was a highly commented point which was also quoted a few times. Considering it was due to pure misunderstanding (which I am to blame, because I wasn't clear enough in the first place) I left a single annotation to indicate that I'm changing the source in order to be completely transparent and visually mark the trail. Not everybody read the edit history and expecting/forcing members to do so is highly optimistic.

Comment: @OlegValter I think it is important to provide transparency and in the most convenient way to the wider audience. I can't really agree with you, especially when you did exactly the opposite by deleting your comments that I've commented on about Yatin's edit to my question. My remarks are left as orphans without any history mechanism to understand/verify the context. Regarding my edit, I really don't see how leaving a simple note detriments the reading experience. For me, it does exactly the opposite.

Comment: @OlegValter Talking about relevance at this stage is a muddy water. After I cleared that members don't get reputation from edits AFTER 2k with my edit, around 20% of the comments should be considered irrelevant. Yet, they are still here and should be because they have archival value even though they realistically just clutter the comment section. I would also argue about the relevance of comments like: "When do we find out the ticket->bitcoin conversion rate and how to use them on Amazon?".

Answer (score 14):

An interesting idea, but I'm inclined to say no for several reasons:

First of all, it allows people to continue asking bad questions as long as they are doing enough community work (suggesting edits). This, imho, lowers the question quality instead of raising it.

Second, most of the moderation tasks the community currently needs, like close-votes, reviews, are not available (and should also not be available) to low-rep users. I wouldn't trust someone who asked 10 0-score questions to perform "First Posts" reviews just because they ran out of tickets. The only options left when you take away reviews are answering questions (hard to do when you're a beginner) or suggesting edits. But why would we want more edits suggested? They just take away more time from reviewers and we already can't handle the amount of suggested edits.

Even if we open up review queues for people who need tickets, who guarantees that they are doing them properly and not just rush over them to gain some tickets. Would we than have to review the reviews?

In total, it sounds like a system that's on one hand works similar to the current question ban system, but allows people to continue asking bad question if they do enough work. And it adds a lot of work to the regulars for reviews or cleanup of useless answers that were just posted to get tickets.

Comment: Not to mention that we are really underequipped to deal with the *current* needs of curation even now - as someone primarily active in the suggested edits queue, I dread the day when the ability to ask will become directly dependent on suggesting an edit for a post...

Comment: I think you're made a misunderstanding between a beginner and someone who has knowledge. There's a lot of users here with Answers: xxxx. Questions: 0.

Comment: The main criticism is based around malicious or non-properly-capable users suggesting edits or cluttering/making bad calls on the review queues. Sorry, I guess I didn't state my point in the question clear enough. First, review queues aren't open to new users for a very good reason and I am not promoting this idea at all. Second, members who don't want to suggest edits won't do it anyway until they exhaust their tickets. And we're not talking about 1 question(ticket) here, we're talking about 10. This is an act that doesn't conclude in 1 or 2 days. More realistically, it takes months. [1/2]

Comment: Also, there is a huge difference between new and malicious users. We shouldn't view them as the same. Asking 10 questions is a long process and you're more likely than not to gather some tickets along the way just by upvotes. If this is not happening, maybe there is a good reason for that and the user should correct his behaviour. Your point revolves around those people who have exhausted their pool of tickets and start cluttering the system with dummy suggested edits to get a ticket or two to continue their rampage. Once again, this is a looong, long process. [2a/2].

Comment: @zhulien: Given how many user complain on meta about having received a question banned every day, I guess I believe a little bit less in the good in people than you do. Even more since I saw what kind of stuff you get to see when you do a lot of reviews.

Comment: Declined edits and reviews lead to revoked privileges. That's what I meant by "the system already has a mechanism to prevent this" in the question. Most of the edits we currently do are to questions from users who have 10+ questions without a single answer or comment. The tendency is for them to continue to spawn new unclear, badly structured ones indefinitely. Also, you're looking at the case where we have malicious users(who disregard any guidelines), have used all their tickets and haven't accrued any in the process, all of this happening in minimal time frame as the general case.[2b/2].

Comment: @zhulien - "Asking 10 questions is a long process" - I have seen brand new users ask 3 questions in a very short amount of time.  At the rate I have seen, 10 questions is nothing, that would happen in a day in an active community.  Of course I have never seen a case, where the user who asked that many questions in a single, actually asked questions that were worth keeping around though.  The fact you are not aware of those low quality questions, speaks volumes, to the foundation of the feature you are suggesting.

Comment: @SecurityHound You're using an exceptional case as the general one. What are you even doing if you're asking 5 questions a day? You consider this a normal behaviour? Also, you're pretty swift with the judgement that I am not aware of what happens in the review queues. To be direct, I actually expect some constructive feedback, you just gave me 2 comments of hinting how incompetent I am.

Comment: I haven’t even asked 5 questions in 10 years.  I stopped asking questions at Stack Overflow many moons ago I just answer questions now.  So any changes to asking a question wouldn’t effect me.  I also never hinted or suggested you were incompetent.  It just appears you are unaware of the lengths users will go to in order to get an answer to their question.  I spend a great deal of thought in the specific words I use in order to avoid any confusion with what I have actually said.  If I didn’t actually say something you can assume I didn’t say it.

Comment: @SecurityHound To repeat myself, I didn't indicate edits don't earn reputation(at all) or at least I thought that it should be understood from the context that I am talking about the general case here and not about users below 2k(after all, I was mentioning 100k + reps). This is on me, I guess, I should have stated that more clearly. Also, about the asking of questions, I wasn't targeting you but the people from your example. Not being fully aware of the question ban is once again fully on me, and I was transparent about that.

Comment: @zhulien - I think you've taken Security Hound's comment on equality too literally. I understand you feel a bit frustrated right now, but it is clear that they are talking about equal *opportunity* to ask and answer which a ticket system seeks to abolish. I expressed my concerns already - I firmly believe in reward-based systems when it comes to incentivizing behaviors (and turns out they do work well, otherwise SO wouldn't be what it is now).

Comment: @OlegValter No, I'm completely aware what he meant. It's just hilarious at this point. He is talking about equal rights for every user to be able to ask a question. I just don't see a point in arguing how the ticket system hinders this. Everybody starts with an equal amount of tickets. If they have any actual sense of what's happening around them, they won't be in a deficit. Otherwise - they do. The question ban seems to work on exactly the same principle. And I don't see how "ban" and "reward-based" system are the same thing for you but my proposal of awarding tickets is actually a penalty.

Comment: Why I see ticket system as a penalty-based one? Quite simple, actually: currently, anyone can ask any amount of questions (q-ban & a-ban are mechanisms that are indeed penalty-based, but they serve a different purpose - they *prevent* sequentially bad content. Not that I like them very much, btw - certainly never said they are part of the reward system). You propose to take that away and give out rations. Once a user exhausts them - they lose the ability to ask *until* they *correct* the behavior - that's a textbook definition of a penalty-based system. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] Such systems can cover up the penalty aspect by saying they "reward" good behavior with tickets/points/coins/you name it, but that's just a psychological trick used to make a person believe they are rewarded when in reality they are spoon-fed what should inherently be able to do from the start. I think you are applying a marketing approach (it is a "freemium" model in a nutshell that just happens to not involve money) where a gentler solution is needed. We need people to answer because it is a rewarding experience in itself, not because otherwise we strip them of their right to ask

Comment: @OlegValter I am now pretty sure we're talking about different things. In my mind, people are not here to "collect" anything. They're here to receive help for a problem they have. Talking about psychological and marketing "tricks" in this context is just.. I don't even know what to say. Nobody "awards" them anything. You give them the ability to receive help yet once again without any compensation if they simply behave. And I strongly believe the ability to receive help freely shouldn't be taken for granted. [1/2]

Comment: @OlegValter Most of the questions I currently encounter (which desperately need an edit to be at least readable, let alone understandable and I mean on the home page, not from review queues) are from users who doesn't give a [blank] about anything and just want help. They open the site, ask a question and leave, then come back a few hours later to fetch the answer without leaving any feedback to the people who provided assistance and leave again. It's just rinse and repeat after this point. [2a/2]

Comment: @OlegValter They have zero incentive to improve their questions because it just works that way for them. If their account gets suspended they just create a new one - zero hassle. If that is the "working solution" we have then be it. [2b/2].

Comment: "awarding tickets" - your words, not mine. This is exactly the "trick" (note that I never indicated this has any malicious connotation) I am referring to: taking something away and then giving it back in small parts and telling this is a reward. People do go here to get help and not to collect - and this exactly why I am firmly against any system that prevents them from doing so because "they did not answer enough" or "edit enough", or whatnot. One and only criteria should be their ability to ask a good question. That's also where curators' importance comes into play, btw.

Comment: Ticket-baded system is in no way different from the "freemium" models of marketing - there is no shame in that. I just disagree that this model is a good solution for an aim of incentivising answers on a community-run free to use Q&A platform. You seem to throw good askers and help vamps into one basket. There is nothing we can do about the latter - they will not start contributing good answers just because they are out of tickets. The only ones who will get hit are exactly the "good" askers.

Comment: @OlegValter At this point, I agree with you. I am not putting them at the same basket at all but maybe my suggested "solution" will lead indeed to that. You're right that seeing it from afar, the decent askers will be the ones "suffering" from this. Thank you!